# Import library tqdm works in python2 but not in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I've been trying to get tqdm to work in my Python 3 code.

I first thought this was a permissions issue, then a Python 3 relative imports issue but neither seems to fit the bill. I can import tqdm just fine in python 2.

I tried doing

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
```

and

```py
from .tqdm import tqdm
```

but I keep getting the no module named tqdm found error with the former and **SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import**
 with the latter.

I tried reinstalling tqdm with pip3, and it says the requirement is already satisfied. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: How have you installed `tqdm` for Python 3?

Comment: I did `pip install tqdm` and `pip3 install tqdm`

Comment: use `python -m pip install tqdm` pthon is keyword yu use to invoke python in your os

Comment: @SR1 You probably have more than 1 Python 3 and `pip3` installs packages for another Python, not for the one you use to run the code that imports `tqdm`.

Comment: @phd is probably right. `tqdm` works fine on my Ubuntu, so the first thing to check is if you've installed it fit the right version of python.